# I need help for search page

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am working on search page and below is the code I am using.

```
public function index(Request $request){

    $data     = $request->input();
    // dd($data);
    $category_id = '';
    $products = Product::select('products.*','b.name as brand_name')
                        ->leftjoin('brands as b','b.id','products.brand_id')
                        ->with('product_image')
                        ->whereHas('product_sizes.product_size')
                        ->whereHas('product_color')
                        ->where('status','A')
                        ->whereNull('b.deleted_at')
                        ->whereNull('products.deleted_at');
                        //->get()
                        //->toArray();


    //echo "<pre>";print_r($products);die;

    $sub_category_id = '';
    if(!empty(@$data['sub_category_id'])){
        $sub_category_id = $data['sub_category_id'];
        $products    = $products->where('products.sub_category_id',$data['sub_category_id']);
        $category_id = SubCategory::where('id',$data['sub_category_id'])
                                   ->whereNull('deleted_at')
                                   ->value('category_id');
    }

    $sub_sub_category_id = '';
    if(!empty(@$data['sub_sub_category_id'])){

        $sub_sub_category_id = $data['sub_sub_category_id'];
        $products    = $products->where('products.sub_sub_category_id',$data['sub_sub_category_id']);

        $sub_category_id = SubSubCategory::where('id',$data['sub_sub_category_id'])
                                   ->whereNull('deleted_at')
                                   ->value('sub_category_id');
        $category_id = SubCategory::where('id',$sub_category_id)
                                   ->whereNull('deleted_at')
                                   ->value('category_id');
        /*$category_id = SubCategory::where('id',$data['sub_sub_category_id'])
                                   ->whereNull('deleted_at')
                                   ->value('category_id');*/
    }
    $brand_id = '';
    if(!empty(@$data['brand_id'])){
        $brand_id    = $data['brand_id'];
        $products    = $products->where('brand_id',$data['brand_id']);
        $category_id = Brand::where('id',$data['brand_id'])
                            ->whereNull('deleted_at')
                            ->value('category_id');
    }

    if(@$_GET['category_id']){

       $category_id    = $_GET['category_id'];           
    }
    if(!empty($category_id)){
        $products = $products->where('products.category_id',$category_id);
    }



    if (!empty(@$data['search'])){
        $search = trim($data['search']);
        // echo $search; die;
        /*$products = $products->where('products.title','like','%'.$search.'%')
                            ->orWhere('products.description','like','%'.$search.'%')
                            ->orWhere('b.name','like','%'.$search.'%');*/

        $products = $products->where(function($q) use($search){
            $q->where('products.title','like','%'.$search.'%')
                ->orWhere('products.description','like','%'.$search.'%')
                ->orWhere('b.name','like','%'.$search.'%');
        });

    // echo "<pre>";print_r($products->get()->toArray());die;


        $categories = Category::with('sub_categories','sub_categories.sub_sub_categories')
                                ->whereNull('deleted_at')
                                ->get()
                                ->toArray();

        $brands    = Brand::select()
                        ->whereNull('deleted_at')
                        ->get()
                        ->toArray();

    }else{

        $sub_categories = SubCategory::with('sub_sub_categories')
                                  ->where('category_id',$category_id)
                                  ->whereNull('deleted_at')
                                  ->get()
                                  ->toArray();

        $brands    = Brand::where('category_id',$category_id)
                        ->whereNull('deleted_at')
                        ->get()
                        ->toArray();
    }

    $products       = $products->get()->toArray();
    // dd($products);
    // dd($categories);

    if(Auth::check()) {
        $user_id = Auth::id();
        $wishlists = Wishlist::select()
                             ->where('user_id',$user_id)
                             ->pluck('product_id')->toArray();
    }
    // echo "<pre>";print_r($products['description'][0]['id']);die;
    $filters = Filter::select('*')
                    ->whereNull('deleted_at')
                    ->orderBy('from_value','asc')
                    ->get()
                    ->toArray();
    // dd($search);
    return view('frontEnd.products.index',compact('products','categories','sub_categories','brands','category_id','wishlists','sub_category_id','brand_id','search','filters','sub_sub_category_id'));
}
```

I want to get products according to `categories` and `subcategories` when selecting on front page. Below is the front page image.`Men wears` is the sub_category and `shirts` is the sub_sub_category. I am getting empty products right now.

[Front end page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsNhN.png)

Below is the product table:-

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id    | category_id    | sub_category_id    | sub_sub_category_id    | title    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1     | 1              | 1                  | 1                      | abc      |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Below is the category table:-

```
--------------------
| id    |  name    |
--------------------
| 1     | men      |
--------------------
```

Below is the sub_category table:-

```
--------------------------------------
| id    | category_id    | name      |
--------------------------------------
| 1     | 1              | men wears |
--------------------------------------
```

Below is the sub_sub_category table:-

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
| id    | category_id    | sub_category_id    | name      |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| 1     | 1              | 1                  | shirts    |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Why do you use `category`, `sub_category`, `sub_sub_category` ?? Why you don't use `parent`, `child`.... etc

Comment: @A.ANoman.. I used for the convenience. Well, thank you I'll use it from now. Thanks :)

Comment: If you search `shirt` `sub_sub_category` then it returns all shirt products is it right?

Comment: @A.ANoman..This is what I want, but it's not happening. No products are showing up. I have attached image. You can get clear view from that.

Comment: I used that type of problem what you faced. First you see this https://nitolelectronics.com/

If you feel you want this then I try to problem your solve

Comment: @A.ANoman. Yes, you are right. This is exactly what I want.

Comment: I have three tables `categories`, `products`,  `products_categories`. Where `products_categories` fields are `id`, `category_id`, `product_id`. Where `products_categories` has `categories_id` of corresponding product

Comment: Okay, I have shown product table above, showing assigned categories id of corresponding product.

Answer (score 0):

You have three Model. `Product`, `Category` and `ProductsCategory`. The relationship `Category` and `Products` as `manyToMany`

In `Category` Model the relationship is below

```
public function products(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product','products_categories','category_id','product_id');
}
```

And in `Product` Model the relationship is below

```
public function categories(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category','products_categories','product_id','category_id');
}
```

And Category Model must be `parent_id`. In your image `Men Wears` is root parent then `Shirts`, `T-Shirts` is child. If you choice Shirts then `All Shirts` products show in your views